# Open PDF after creating it programmaticaly

Tags: magento2, pdf

i have my function that generate my PDF, this works fine (the function is in my block).

After that, i want to show the window with this (this is in my controller)

```
ob_start();
header("Content-Length: " . filesize ( $fullUrl ) );
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($fullUrl));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullUrl);
```

but **readfile** doesn't do anything. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try below code**

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $fileFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');
    $fileName = 'example'.\date('m-d-Y_hia').'.txt';
    $pdfObject = @file_get_contents($fullUrl);
    $fileFactory->create(
               $fileName,
               $pdfObject,
               \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
               'application/pdf'
            );
```

Comment: My file already exists, could you please give explanation ?

Comment: Above code downloads pdf from file you provided.
Do you want to preview pdf or you want download it.

Comment: Yeah, downloads would be great. But could you please add the code to preview the pdf? Could be useful